I've set up the proxy and added the security certificate in Chrome for JMeter, but JMeter isn't logging any actions when I run and stop them in Chrome
I am new to jmeter I am using test script recoder. I've set up the proxy in chrome and added it in jmeter. I've also included the security certificate in chrome for jmeter. But when I start any action on chrome and stops the jmeter, it does not logs those actions in jmeter
I've set up the proxy in chrome and added it in jmeter. I've also included the security certificate in chrome for jmeter. But when I start any action on chrome and stops the jmeter, it does not logs those actions in jmeter

In its current form your question cannot be comprehensively answered, try checking:

Chrome console for any eventual errors
jmeter.log file for any suspicious entries

and update your question with the output from the above sources if you won't able to figure out the root cause yourself.
In the meantime I can suggest an alternative approach to recording a JMeter test: JMeter Chrome Extension, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.
